# How clear is it that Tolkien chose the 25th of March for the downfall of Sauron because of its Christian significance?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, religion, j-r-r-tolkien

The downfall of Sauron and the end of the War of the Ring occurred on the [25th of March](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/25_March) in the year 3019 of the Third Age. Many [scholars](https://www.teawithtolkien.com/blog/2017/2/11/the-significance-of-march-25th) and [critics](https://www.ncregister.com/blog/astagnaro/j.r.r.-tolkien-the-feast-of-the-annunciation-and-the-defeat-of-sauron) have [speculated](https://www.dominicanajournal.org/the-annunciation-and-the-one-ring/) that Tolkien chose this date specifically because of its relevance in the Christian calendar as the [Feast of the Annunciation](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/01542a.htm). This indeed seems very likely to be the case, given the immense significance of the date both in Middle-earth history and in Christian tradition, and the fact that Tolkien was a devout Catholic.

**Did Tolkien ever confirm that he chose the date for this reason?** Failing that, what information *do* we have from which the strongest argument can be built up for the connection not being a coincidence - e.g. about Christian themes present in LotR, or about his choice of other significant dates in the story?

Comment: [Similar question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/90616/31394) about the 15th of March.

Comment: What's the next date in the series?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot The 25th of March connection is a hell of a lot more likely than the 15th of March one.

Comment: I may note that in medieval times may European countries celebrated New Year's Day on March 25, the Feast of the Annunciation, so that March 24, 1313, might be followed by March  25, 1314.  William the Conqueror (r. 1066-1087) established January 1 as the New's Day in England, but it was changed to March 25 in the 12th century I think, and not changed back to January 1 until, and not changed back until 1752.   The appendix on calendars in Return of the King says that March 25 became the beginning of the year to celebrate the downfall of Sauron.